# HAAR classifier-how to detect only ONE face at a time

Tags: c#, opencv, haar-classifier

Using a C# implementation of Open CV which in turn is directly based on the OpenCV Java source here.
http://docs.opencv.org/java/

The specific line where I call the HAAR classifier is

```
 cascade.detectMultiScale(grayMat, faces, 1.2, 3, 2, new Size(60, 60), new Size(150, 150));
```

The problem is I only want to track one face at a time, even if several are detected. ie if there are 2 faces detected, my tracking rectangles keep jumping randomly between the 2 faces.
How can I ONLY detect 1 face at a time(ie the first one detected)?

Comment: use camshift for trackling object after first detection, should be better

Comment: Not sure what you mean by camshift, could you clarify?

Comment: _camshift_ is a tracking algorithm (just google it). With the first detection you initialize the tracker, then you track the head (no more detections).