# Face Tracking OpenCV

Tags: android, opencv, face-detection

How I can get only one face tracking on the frame?
Now I can detect and tracking face using Haar already.

But if on the frame has many faces.

Program will track all faces but I want it detect only one face.

this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32059717/haar-classifier-how-to-detect-only-one-face-at-a-time) suggest using camshift then kalman filter.

Did it has other way to do it?

Thank you and sorry for confused English.

Answer (score 1):

After applying the MultiScale Cascade classifier, as following:

```
 ...       
 MatOfRect faces = new MatOfRect();
 mJavaDetector.detectMultiScale(imagem_gray, faces, 1.1, 2, 2, new Size(mAbsoluteFaceSize, mAbsoluteFaceSize), new Size());
```

And then...

```
Rect[] facesArray = faces.toArray();
if (facesArray.length > 0) //... do whatever you want
```

You can therefore access each face individually. 
Ex, `facesArray[0]`, you have the `Rect` related to the face 0

Comment: Is face 0 the biggest face?. Or it is the first appear in frame.

Comment: The first one. Every element of facesArray (Rect!), has a size. If you want the biggest face, you could order it by its size.